# Nested loop over a query

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query which provide results like say

```
Col1ID      Col2    Col3    Col4
1           cfml    34      56.5
3           Java    34      56.5
8           Jquery  36      57.7
34          .Net    34      52.2
63           php    34      56.5
7           extjs   36      57.7
```

Now the problem is if Col3 & Col4 values are both identical in more than one row, col4 value need to be changed, say make it +1. Do I convert Col3 & Col4 to arrays and then compare? Or Do I loop over query and nest loop inside to same query. Or any other alternative..

**EDIT**:

I need to compare the pair values of col3 & col4 with next rows or previous rows for that matter.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to display? It seems like you'd be better off grouping by Col2 and Col3. Is Col4 based on some calculation related to the frequency of the values in Col3?

Comment: iKnowKungFoo, grouping is not possible. The data comes from a 3rd party and I do not have much control over that. So basically if col3 is values at 24 and col4 is 44, no other row could have the same value pair of 24/44.

Comment: *with next rows or previous rows for that matter.* Depends on exactly what you mean by that.  If you simply need to compare the values in each *row* with those in the previous row (based on the some predefined sort order), use the `currentRow` variable and array notation to perform the comparison. Then perform some action when the values are the same. Otherwise, you would need to elaborate on the exact rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array of those values and check if it has already been displayed. If it has then add 1 and add that new value to your array

```
<cfset col3Values = []>
<cfoutput query="myQuery">
  <cfif arrayFind(col3Values, myQuery.col3)>
    <cfset displayValue = myQuery.col3 + 1>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset displayValue = myQuery.col3>
  </cfif>
  #displayValue#
  <cfset arrayAppend(col3Values, displayValue)>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Matt, but my problem is (sorry, was not clear with that in question) that I have to check the value of pair col3 & col4 with next rows

Answer (score -1):

You only need one loop.  You just need to initialize your variables beforehand.

```
<cfset col4Value = "nothing, and this will work because ColdFusion is not 
strongly typed">
<cfset col3Value = col4Value>

<cfloop query = "yourquery">
<cfif col3 is not col3value>
code 
</cfif>
same thing for col4
<cfset col3Value = yourquery['col3'][currentrow]>
<cfset col4Value = yourquery['col4'][currentrow]>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem? You're just setting things into a variable.

Comment: The line between the cfloop and cfset is the spot where the OP writes code to do what needs to be done.  That didn't seem to be the part he need help with.